# Как извлечь текст из двух списков

Tags: python, list

Есть список с раной вложенностью, и нужно получить текст (Test_1-8) который в скобках.
Примеры возможный вложенностей:

```
doc_list = ['Test_1', 'Test_2', 'Test_3']
doc_list = [['Test_4', 'Test_5', 'Test_6'], ['Test_7']]
```

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Comment: Что значит "извлечь"? Если извлечь весь текст из списков, то в них ничего не останется. ;)

Comment: Получить текст Test_1 - Test_8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472564/4804629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую уточнить как именно должно вывести все в строчку или отдельно(я так понял)

```
    doc_list = ['Test_1', 'Test_2', 'Test_3']
    doc_list_1 = [['Test_4', 'Test_5', 'Test_6'], ['Test_7'], ['Test_8']]

    for i in doc_list:
        print(i)

    for i in doc_list_1:
        for k in i :
            print(k)
```

Вывод будет таким :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если надо по другому пиши

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, но есть одно НО: ТС игнорирует правила хорошего тона и полагает, что здесь решат все его задачи без усилий с его стороны. Поэтому комментарии под вопросом достаточно язвительны. Я принимаю сторону сообщества и считаю, что ответы на такие вопросы только подогревают интерес халявщиков к решению простеших учебных заданий. Не удаляйте, пускай будет, но в дальнейшем можно воздержаться от ответа

Comment: @Dmitry
Ладно я согласен, задача реально легкая такую в шк я наверно делал.

Comment: Благодарю ребята за помощь, немного протупил с постановкой вопроса. Уже второй день мучаюсь с этой вложенностью.